# Flask/Peewee Delete A Row

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, peewee, flask-peewee

I am using Peewee with Flask. I have a table of parts that I want to be able to add to, delete and update from a form. I have the add part working and am working on the delete function. This function will delete a row from the db that is equal to the part name given on the form. Here is my code:

**Python/Flask**
*app.py*

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def admin():
    form = forms.PartsUpdateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        choice = request.form.get('admin_choice')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if choice == 'add_part':
            models.Parts.create(part_name=form.part_name.data, part_desc=form.part_desc.data,
                                part_img=form.part_img.data)
            flash("Part Created! Thanks!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        elif choice == 'update_part':
            flash('UPDATE : WIP')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            to_del = form.part_name.data
            to_del.delete()
            flash("Part deleted!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The else statement activates the deletion portion but I can't seem to get it to actually delete. I read the peewee docs and I guess I'm not understanding the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I figured it out. I needed to actually ref the db and use delete_instance.

**Python**
*app.py*

```
    else:
        to_del = Parts.get(Parts.part_name == form.part_name.data)
        to_del.delete_instance()
        flash("Part deleted!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```